# showing that there exist only one function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

need some help with this question:
Let $\Omega \neq \mathbb C$ a simply connected area. Let $w_0 \in \Omega, z_0 \in D=\{z: |z|<1\}$ and $-\pi<\theta<\pi $

I want to show that there exist only one function $f$ such that:
$f$ is bijection, $f(D)=\Omega$, $f(z_0)=w_0$ and $arg f'(z_0)=0$

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\theta$? Where are you stuck: existence or uniqueness?

Comment: Did you mean $\text{arg} f'(z_0) = \theta$ ?

Comment: Presumably you want $f$ to be holomorphic on all of $D$ (not just complex differentiable at $z_0$, which is all that can be inferred from what you wrote).  Without this condition there is no uniqueness (and no conceivable use of the result, really).  I suggest web and textbook searches for "Riemann mapping theorem".  The references in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem are a good start.